# relu as a parameter in Dense() ( or any other layer) vs ReLu as a layer in Keras

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I was just wondering if there is any significant difference between the use and speciality of

```
Dense(activation='relu')
```

and

```
keras.layers.ReLu
```

How and where the later one can be used? My best guess is in Functional API usecase but I don't know how.

Comment: Please, don't forget accept my answer if you are satisfied with it, thank you.

Comment: Please read my update, as I missed your last question

Comment: Sure and thank you for the help that  was much insightful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating some `Layer` instance passing the activation as parameter i.e. `activation='relu'` is the same as creating some `Layer` instance and then creating an activation e.g. `Relu` instance. `Relu()` is a layer which returns `K.relu()` function over `inputs`:

```
class ReLU(Layer):
.
.
.
     def call(self, inputs):
            return K.relu(inputs,
                          alpha=self.negative_slope,
                          max_value=self.max_value,
                          threshold=self.threshold)
```

From the Keras documentation:

> **Usage of activations**
>
> Activations can either be used through an Activation layer, or through
>   the activation argument supported by all
>   forward layers:
>
> ```
> from keras.layers import Activation, Dense
>
> model.add(Dense(64))
> model.add(Activation('tanh'))
> ```
>
> This is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> model.add(Dense(64, activation='tanh'))
> ```
>
> You can also pass an element-wise TensorFlow/Theano/CNTK function as
>   an activation:
>
> ```
> from keras import backend as K
>
> model.add(Dense(64, activation=K.tanh))
> ```

**Update:**

Answering OP's aditional question: *How and where the later one can be used?*:

You can use it when you used some layer, which doesn't accept `activation` parameter like e.g. `tf.keras.layers.Add`, `tf.keras.layers.Subtract` etc, but you want to get a rectified output of such layers as a result:

```
added = tf.keras.layers.Add()([x1, x2])
relu = tf.keras.layers.ReLU(added)
```

Answer (score 2):

The most obvious use case is when you need to put a ReLU without a `Dense` layer, for example when implementing ResNet, the design requires a ReLU activation after summing the residual connection, like it is shown [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-applications/blob/master/keras_applications/resnet50.py#L138):

```
x = layers.add([x, shortcut])
x = layers.Activation('relu')(x)
return x
```

It is also useful when you want to put a `BatchNormalization` layer between the pre-activation of a `Dense` layer and the ReLU activation. When using a `GlobalAveragePooling` classifier (such as in the SqueezeNet architecture), then you need to put a softmax activation after the GAP using `Activation("softmax")` and there are no `Dense` layers in the network.

There are probably more cases, these are just samples.

Comment: can these be used separately without any layer or they HAVE to follow a layer such as Dense?

Comment: The ResNet example shows how to use them without a Dense layer, there are no such restrictions